# Listing Files Using PHP

Tags: php, list, file-io

I'm needing to make a web site, that should list all the files that are in the directory `/Files`(where `/` is the Apache public - `htdocs`), but excluding if there is any sub-directory. Also, they should have links for every file. Like this:

```
echo "<a href='Link to the file'>Test.doc</a>" . "\n"
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glob` finds files by a matching pattern. That's not needed here, so you could also use the [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php):

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator('/pub/files') as $directoryItem) {
    if($directoryItem->isFile()) {
        printf('<a href="/files/%1$s">%1$s</a>', $directoryItem->getBasename());
    }
}
```

Further reading:

- [Bill Karwin's Putting glob() to the test](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/28/putting-glob-to-the-test/)
- [Introduction to Spl](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, the DirectoryIterator doesn't return SplFileInfo.   Not that that makes any difference to the code shown.

Comment: @salathe ok, current() returns DirectoryIterator, which extends from SplFileInfo? Better? :)

Comment: @Gordon: It works, but when I click on the links, what I got is this: `The requested URL ... was not found on this server.`. Check it out: surl.x10.mx/list.php

Comment: @Nathan if you look at the href attribute, you will see they have the full server path, e.g. `/home/nathanpc/public_html/filename` - this won't work. A `/` at the beginning of a URI means relative to the document root, so the link points to the server path `/home/nathanpc/public_html/home/nathanpc/public_html/filename`. If the filename is in public_html, just use `/filename`.

Answer (score 2):

Use "glob()" function.

```
<?php
    foreach(glob('/*') as $file)
      if(is_file($file))
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.basename($file).'</a>';
?>
```

For your info, this kind of thing is called "directory listing", which Apache sometimes does by default when there's no index (html, htm, php asp..) file.

Comment: don't use `*.*` as the pattern. `*` works fine and matches files without an extension (or files that just have an extension)

Comment: Doesn't that also match folders? Let me change the code again...fixed

Comment: Looks like a PHP issue to me. Do you have PHP installed and enabled?
If you go to View->View Source, you'll see the full PHP code, which is not right. That is, the file is not executed at all.